# Java runtime error with JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, runtime-error

I am trying to build and run an example jni program.  The program is just a sample helloworld program.   I did not write it but I assume that it works.  I am running this on Linux.  There are four files.

```
HelloNative.c  
HelloNative.h  
HelloNative.java  
HelloNativeTest.java
```

To build the files, I did

```
gcc -I/myDir/jdk/include -I/myDir/jdk/include/linux -fPIC -c HelloNative.c  
gcc -shared -o HelloNative.so HelloNative.o  
java *java
```

Here is the result of the build

```
HelloNative.c  
HelloNative.h  
     HelloNative.o  
   HelloNativeTest.class  
HelloNative.class  
HelloNative.java  
HelloNative.so  
HelloNativeTest.java
```

Then I did

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /myDir/myExample:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}  
java HelloNativeTest
```

I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no HelloNative in java.library.path  
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)  
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)  
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)  
        at HelloNative.<clinit>(HelloNative.java:9)  
        at HelloNativeTest.main(HelloNativeTest.java:8)
```

I checked the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the `HelloClassTest` and `HelloNative.so`, they were all there.   I tried to specify the `-CLASSPATH` also, but that did not seem to matter.
Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't have the C files have the same name as the Java files. There's

Comment: The files were from a tutorial package.   I did not modify or rename them.   I assume they work as is.   I could try to modify and rename them.   Are you sure that is the problem ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell people where they can download the sample from so they might try it. Also have you modified anything at all from the sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following, where X="HelloNative".

- Give the library a filename following a system-dependent standard. On Linux, name your library `libX.so`.
- Set the `java.library.path` System property to the directory containing your library.
- Call `System.loadLibrary("X")` where "X" is the cross-platform *part* of the library name above.

You named your library `HelloNative.so`; change it to `libHelloNative.so.`

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp679:

> The argument to System.loadLibrary is
>   a library name chosen arbitrarily by
>   the programmer. The system follows a
>   standard, but platform-specific,
>   approach to convert the library name
>   to a native library name. For example,
>   a Solaris system converts the name
>   pkg_Cls to libpkg_Cls.so, while a
>   Win32 system converts the same pkg_Cls
>   name to pkg_Cls.dll.

If you use OSGi in the future, there's an alternative to setting `java.library.path.`

Comment: Yes, thank you Andy.   Changing the HelloNative.so to libHelloNative.so did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by setting the `java.library.path`:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/myDir/myExample HelloNativeTest
```

Comment: That option did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a System.loadLibrary() from Java?

Comment: Like I said this is straight from Sun Java tutorial package.   I assume they know what they are doing.   I did check and they did have class HelloNative  
{  public static native void greeting();    
   static  
   {  System.loadLibrary("HelloNative");  
   }  
}

Comment: Libraries on Linux are expected to begin with "lib". Try renaming to libHelloNative.so?